Why does the Bhagavata Purana contain erotic and sexual descriptions?
I thought I could become pure by reading the Bhagavatam but it has shaken my faith a little bit. I've been reading the stories and I can't help but feel guilty for reading the sexual descriptions of women's bodies in the Bhagavatam.
Especially something like the episode Mohini and Lord Shiva. The avatar was naked and there's a lot of talk about her breasts and all.
This has caused me great trouble and I'm having a really hard time becoming pure. Could someone please explain why such descriptions exist and how can one avoid fall downs after reading such things? The mind is very tricky, it justifies that lust is okay sometimes because even Gods aren't an exception.
How is a devotee in Kali Yuga ever supposed to deal with this? With all the lustful descriptions that shake your bhakti?

Sexual union is just a distraction. There are chapter on krisha and Gopis as well. It’s on us how to see it. Union is with divine, seems like union with divine is beyond the sexual pleasure. Sanatan Dharm never says sexual union is taboo. Even all the rishis were married. These things have esoteric meanings. If i find answers will share gradually.

Short Answer
The Bhagavata Purana is not to be read by those whose minds seek enjoyment in lust. It is the Bhagavad Gita which is to be studied before any other scripture by those who wish to become devotees of Lord Krishna.
Otherwise, there's a great risk of misunderstanding the descriptions for mundane lust causing one to fall from spiritual life.
Bhagavata Purana is a more advanced scripture which is meant for serious spiritual aspirants. It is to be studied systematically and/or heard from a self-realized or advanced devotee of Lord Vishnu or Krishna.
Long Answer
The Bhagavata Purana is not the first scripture to be read to extinguish the fire of lust. The Bhagavad Gita is meant for this purpose through guidance of a bonafide spiritual master to internally realize the nature of oneself (atman) as spoken by Lord Krishna. The Bhagavata Purana is meant for the advanced or serious devotees of Lord Krishna who engage in regular spiritual Sadhana as instructed by their spiritual master or Guru.
The Puranas were written in an era when the minds of people were not constantly agitated by lust as they led their lives as per Dharma viz. Brahmacharya, Grihasta, Vanaprastha, and Sanyasa.

aśuddhāḥ śūdra-kalpā hi brāhmaṇāḥ kali-sambhavāḥ
Because there is no cultural education in this age of Kali, everyone
is spiritually untrained, and everyone is therefore to be considered
śūdra unless they're trained in spiritual life (Visnu Yamala).

After becoming spiritually trained, scriptures such as the Bhagavata are to be heard from pure Vaishnavas whose Vani (transcendental sound vibrations) emanates the realization of the absolute truth.
Aural reception (śrutekṣita patha) from such advanced speakers is the right means to acquire spiritual knowledge rather than reading by oneself, especially in today's times.

tvam bhakti-yoga-paribhāvita-hṛt-saroja āsse śrutekṣita-patho nanu
nātha pumsām
O my Lord, Your devotees can see You through the ears by the process
of bona fide hearing, and thus their hearts become cleansed, and You
take Your seat there (Bhagavata Purana 3.9.11)

Lord Krishna's activities are to be heard by the sincere spiritual aspirants only. Otherwise, one may equate them to mundane eroticism and fall deeper into sense enjoyment than before. This applies to most of the descriptions including Lord Mahadeva's attraction to Mohini Avataram.

sa uttamaśloka mahan-mukha-cyuto bhavat-padāmbhoja-sudhā kaṇānilaḥ
smṛtim punar vismṛta-tattva-vartmanām kuyoginām no vitaraty alam
varaiḥ
My dear Lord, You are glorified by the selected verses uttered by
great personalities. Such glorification of Your lotus feet is just
like saffron particles. When the transcendental vibration from the
mouths of great devotees carries the aroma of the saffron dust of Your
lotus feet, the forgetful living entity gradually remembers his
eternal relationship with You. Devotees thus gradually come to the
right conclusion about the value of life. My dear Lord, I therefore do
not need any other benediction but the opportunity to hear from the
mouth of Your pure devotee (Bhagavata Purana 4.20.25).

The descriptions are meant to extinguish the remaining few sparks of material desires from the hearts of the self-realized devotees.

praviṣṭaḥ karṇa-randhreṇa svānām bhāva-saroruham dhunoti śamalam
kṛṣṇaḥ salilasya yathā śarat
The sound incarnation of Lord Kṛṣṇa, the Supreme Soul [i.e.
Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam], enters into the heart of a self-realized devotee,
sits on the lotus flower of his loving relationship, and thus cleanses
the dust of material association, such as lust, anger and hankering.
Thus it acts like autumnal rains upon pools of muddy water (Bhagavata Purana 2.8.5).


So are you basically stereotyping sudras being sexually licentious & unfit of aspiring for spirituality ?

Anyone who purposefully becomes licentious will become disqualified to internally realize certain sections of the scriptures meant for the Paramahansas, be it a Shudra or a so called Brahmana. This especially applies to Shrimad Bhagavatam which is known as the Paramahamsa Samhita.

Without having at least some realization of the spirit soul as explained in the Gita, one can't approach the Bhagavatam. Otherwise, one would arrive to a wrong conclusion, especially about the activities of Lord Krishna which are beyond the three gunas.

Firstly, get rid of the prudishness of the Abrahamic faiths that translate our texts like this. There is nothing wrong with eroticism or sex as that is an essential function of self-preservation thru procreation! It is a perfectly normal biological function.
Secondly, get rid of this notion that Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva represent "gods" of Hindu traditions. They are not. They are, from the perspective of temporal reality, abstract concepts. In the spiritual realms (higher realities), they are perceptible "aspects" of the "ultimate reality", the unknowable Brhm.
Once you get this, you'll be able to understand what is being described in the Bhagavatam.
Before the "porn" that is envisaged (translations done when viewing our texts thru the lens of Christian theology), here's what Vishu asserts (don't take this literally either, there is a bhava underlying such descriptions. Get to that):

08120150 śrībhagavān uvāca    08120151 kautūhalāya daityānāṁ yoṣidveṣo
mayā dhṛtaḥ    08120153 paśyatā surakāryāṇi gate pīyūṣabhājane   
08120161 tat te 'haṁ darśayiṣyāmi didṛkṣoḥ surasattama    08120163
kāmināṁ bahu mantavyaṁ saṅkalpaprabhavodayam 

So how do you interpret this?
To paraphrase, Vedvyasa (the author) wants to convey the effects of duality, maya.
And what causes Maya?
Our material nature, our asuric qualities, where the mind drifts outward to sense-objects (prvritti). When your mind drifts outward to sense objects, you see Mohini (moha-ni, the object of desire). But if you had control over your indriya (indriya-nigra), and remained centered on the Atma (atma-vilina), who do you see? You'll see only Vishnu, sakshat!
Here's the whole description (without the porn):

08120170 śrīśu ka uvāca  08120171 iti bruvāṇo
bhagavāṁstatraivāntaradhīyata     08120173
sarvataścārayaṁścakṣurbhava āste sahomayā  08120181 tato
dadarśopavanevarastriyaṁ vicitrapuṣpāruṇapallavadrume  08120183
vikrīḍatīṁkandukalīlayā lasad dukūlaparyastanitambamekhalām 
08120191 āvartanodvartanakampitastana prakṛṣṭahārorubharaiḥ pade pade
 08120193 prabhajyamānāmiva madhyataścalat padapravālaṁ nayatīṁ
tatastataḥ 
08120201 dikṣu bhramatkandukacāpalairbhṛśaṁ
prodvignatārāyatalolalocanām  08120203 svakarṇavibhrājitakuṇḍalollasat
kapolanīlālakamaṇḍitānanām 08120211 ślathaddukūlaṁ kabarīṁ ca vicyutāṁ
sannahyatīṁ vāmakareṇa valgunā 08120213 vinighnatīmanyakareṇa kandukaṁ
vimohayantīṁ jagadātmamāyayā 08120221 tāṁ vīkṣya deva iti
kandukalīlayeṣad vrīḍāsphuṭasmitavisṛṣṭakaṭākṣamuṣṭaḥ 08120223
strīprekṣaṇapratisamīkṣaṇavihvalātmā nātmānamantika umāṁ svagaṇāṁśca
veda 08120231 tasyāḥ karāgrāt sa tu kanduko yadā gato vidūraṁ
tamanuvrajatstriyāḥ 08120233 vāsaḥ sasūtraṁ laghu māruto 'harad
bhavasya devasya kilānupaśyataḥ 08120241 evaṁ tāṁ rucirāpāṅgīṁ
darśanīyāṁ manoramām 08120243 dṛṣṭvā tasyāṁ manaścakre viṣajjantyāṁ
bhavaḥ kila 08120251 tayāpahṛtavijñānastatkṛtasmaravihvalaḥ 08120253
bhavānyā api paśyantyā gatahrīstatpadaṁ yayau 08120261 sā
tamāyāntamālokya vivastrā vrīḍitā bhṛśam 08120263 nilīyamānā vṛkṣeṣu
hasantī nānvatiṣṭhata 08120271 tāmanvagacchadbhagavān bhavaḥ
pramuṣitendriyaḥ 08120273 kāmasya ca vaśaṁ nītaḥ kareṇumiva yūthapaḥ
08120281 so 'nuvrajyātivegena gṛhītvānicchatīṁ striyam 08120283
keśabandha upānīya bāhubhyāṁ pariṣasvaje 08120291 sopagūḍhā bhagavatā
kariṇā kariṇī yathā 08120293 itastataḥ prasarpantī viprakīrṇaśiroruhā
08120301 ātmānaṁ mocayitvāṅga surarṣabhabhujāntarāt 08120303 prādravat
sā pṛthuśroṇī māyā devavinirmitā 08120311 tasyāsau padavīṁ rudro
viṣṇoradbhutakarmaṇaḥ 08120313 pratyapadyata kāmena vairiṇeva
vinirjitaḥ 08120321 tasyānudhāvato retaścaskandāmogharetasaḥ 08120323
śuṣmiṇo yūthapasyeva vāsitāmanudhāvataḥ 08120331 yatra yatrāpatan
mahyāṁ retastasya mahātmanaḥ 
āsan mahīpate 08120341 saritsaraḥsu śaileṣu vaneṣūpavaneṣu ca 08120343
yatra kva cāsannṛṣayastatra sannihito haraḥ 08120351 skanne retasi so
'paśyadātmānaṁ devamāyayā 08120353 jaḍīkṛtaṁ nṛpaśreṣṭha sannyavartata
kaśmalāt 08120361 athāvagatamāhātmya ātmano jagadātmanaḥ 08120363
aparijñeyavīryasya na mene tadu hādbhutam 08120371
tamaviklavamavrīḍamālakṣya madhusūdanaḥ 08120373 uvāca paramaprīto
bibhrat svāṁ pauruṣīṁ tanum

Our material qualities serve the purpose of self-preservation. Our bodily functions are an aspect of self-preservation. There is nothing wrong with sex or eroticism, as the Kama Shastra expouses.
But that's not the purpose of the treatise - the Bhagavatam.
Learn to get to the bhava! The bhava-artha!

Perhaps it comes from an influence of non-Hindu cultural views.
In Hindu culture and mythology there it is normal to describe a man's valour strength and anatomy as well as a woman's beauty, grace or attractiveness with objectiveness. Lord Rama has been described as long strong armed and  Mata Durga as having long plaits of hair or heavy breasted female form.
There is no vulgarity in alluding to sensuous feminine form or any shame in old age. A child's existential view of female breast as source of nourishment cannot be in later life growth turn  obscene.
There are several references in Devi Stothra to divine beauty as well as in Vishwa Kavi Ravindranath Tagore's descriptions of such life imparting grace.

Just Misunderstanding Of Translation, As Sanskrit Has Many Meanings For One Word In That Case People Translate The Sloka With The Meanings Of The Word They Know, In Reality Puranas Have No Wrong Stories And If Any Story In Purans Mentions Anything Then There Is A Lesson Behind That,Infact According To 12.3.14 Of Bhagwat Purana Many Stories Are Written Just To Give Teachings:
इमास्ते कथिता महीयसां
विताय लोकेषु यशः परेयुषाम् ।
विज्ञानवैराग्यविवक्षया विभो
वचोविभूतीर्न तु पारमार्थ्यम् ॥ १४ ॥

O King Parīkṣit! It is with the intention of elucidating (the knowledge of) the unsubstantial nature of the world and to create (a sense of) renunciation about it, that these legends of those illustrious persons who after spreading their great renown in this world, had passed away, have been narrated to you. And all this (picturesque) narration is not mere display of words but bears vital relation to the highest truth!

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana/d/doc1129007.html
So In Reality There Is No Such things In Puranas.

Why did you Added Translation Of Fake Translator Prabhupad I Am Against Of Prabhupad's Translation As Prabhupad Changes Translation Of Gita 2.53, Bhagwat Purana 1.3.22 Prabhupad Translates Athiest Ravana Which Isnt Written In Actual Sloka, Bhagwat Purana 11.5.13 Is Against Of Pashubali But Prabhupad Translation Promotes Pashubali
